# Polidea/ios-class-guard - obfuscate_project is stuck

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bash, obfuscation

I'm using `ios-class-guard` for the first time and can't get it to work.

I was able to install it using `brew install ios-class-guard`

Downloaded `obfuscate_project` using `curl -o obfuscate_project https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard/master/contrib/obfuscate_project && chmod +x obfuscate_project`

Edited the following:

```
# General build options
WORKSPACE=MyProj.xcworkspace
# PROJECT=MyProj.xcodeproj
SCHEME=MyProj
CONFIGURATION=Release
SDK=9.2
```

Did `bash obfuscate_project`

The output looks something like this:

```
git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 7f2471a 2
git clean -fdx
xcodebuild -workspace MyProj.xcworkspace -scheme MyProj -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator9.2 clean build -derivedDataPath build
2016-03-10 16:59:00.521 xcodebuild[86029:5492619] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/StencilPlugin.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-03-10 16:59:00.523 xcodebuild[86029:5492619] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/xxx/Xcode/MyProj/build

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator9.2
```

and it doesn't do anything at this stage...

I'm using El Capitan 10.11.3, Xcode 7.2.1

What am I missing?

Comment: Potentially related: https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard/issues/32  Did you try a cleaning your build folder before running `obfuscate_project`?

Comment: I've just tried it.. same result :(